# Is it possible to use jsforce to achieve Schema.DescribeFieldResult?

Tags: salesforce, jsforce, salesforce-development

wondered if anyone has used jsForce to retrieve metadata about custom fields - per what is possible via the DescribeFieldResult call described here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm

Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the [REST API "describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm)", for example `/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Account/describe`

[image]

Or write a piece of Apex that would run your describe call and [expose it as a REST service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm) using `@HttpGet` for example. Then call it with `apexrest` in the URL