# To get schema of Salesforce tables

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I have a read access in salesforce account and we would like to explore the data in Salesforce DB.

We have a DWH based on Postgres and would like the schema/tables from Salesforce to be imported into our DWH.Below are the tables that we are interested in.

We are using a third party solution to connect Salesforce and our DWH, While connecting we could access 2 endpoints (Salesforce Reporting & Salesforce Query). I would like to access the Salesforce Query and pull information into our DWH.

The problem I'm facing is , I cannot put "SELECT *" in the query and need to input the COLUMN names separately, But even-though I have searched in Google I didn't find the SCHEMA of the below tables.

Any help or reference, I could get to find the schema(column names) of the below mentioned tables.

Or Is there any other way I could connect and able to find the schema of the Salesforce.

```
Account
Contact
Opportunity
Case
Lead
Activity (Task/Event)
Sales User
Account Team Member
Partner Role
Contract
Lead
Quote
Asset
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may have access to "Schema Builder" (Setup -> Object Manager -> button in top right), may help. There are some tools to help you with writing queries, you could use sfdx + vscode, https://workbench.developerforce.com/, the [Chrome plugin](https://github.com/sorenkrabbe/Chrome-Salesforce-inspector) is pretty neat.

These will be neat but it'll be only core salesforce, without any custom additions your admins built on top: https://architect.salesforce.com/diagrams/template-gallery/sales-cloud-overview-data-model

If you need programmatic access to metadata - search for salesforce "describe" operations. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75218450/313628 (shameless plug)

If you need a shorthand like SQL Server's "SELECT TOP" - see if your tool supports "FIELDS(ALL)". https://stackoverflow.com/a/75100943/313628

And finally - metadata is also stored in special system tables. When all else fails try https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067076/313628